# How to figure out the running time one's algorithm is supposed to take by looking at the constraints given in problems on sites like Hackerrank.com?

Tags: performance

I know that every language is given a maximum time to execute the program(It is 2 seconds for C++). Given that, how can I be able to tell if my algorithm shouldn't be anymore than O(n) or O(n^2),etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate that judging by the dataset you would be operating on.

Let's say that

- `N` is the maximum number of elements you alghorithm would operate on
- `TL` is your total time limit, which would be 2 seconds for C++
- `L` is your time limit for processing a single element.

In that case `L` is calculated as `TL` divided by time-complexity for you `N`.
E.g. for `TL=2` and `N=10^2`:

- For a `O(n)` alghorithm `L=2/10^2=2*10^-2` which means you could spend not more than 0,02 seconds (20 milliseconds) for each element.
- For a `O(n*logn)` alghorithm `L=2/(10^2*log10^2)=2/(10^2*6)=3*10^-3` which means you could spend not more than 0,003 seconds (3 milliseconds) for each element
- For a `O(n^2)` alghorithm `L=2/(10^2^2)=2*10^-4` which means you could spend not more than 0,0002 seconds (0,2 milliseconds, i.e. 200 microseconds).

The bigger `N` gets - the less time you have for your processing literally.

Now, when you have estimated your boundaries for a single element you can estimate how much you could really do. Simple arithmetics, function calls take nanoseconds, memory accesses could take a factor of 10 nanoseconds ([cpu time cost estimation taken from here](http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/)).

So as a rule of a thumb - if you've done the calculation for your alghorithm and dataset and you get less than 2*10^-7 - it's quite likely that you won't make it in 2 seconds.

Please note, that for this calculation you shouldn't omit constant factors (i.e. it's better to take as close time-complexity as you can get like O(n*logn + n) or O(3*n)) as they would affect the estimation.